# Сгруппировать числовые элементы массива

Tags: javascript

есть данный массив.

`let  arr = [171, 22, 37, 2, 123, 54, 8, 7]`.

Надо его привести к вот такому виду.

`[ [2, 7, 8], [22, 37, 54], [123, 171] ]`.

Пробовал через reduce, но что-то не вышло. Буду рад помощи.

Comment: по какому принципу должны группироваться элементы?

Comment: я за логарифм..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так понял Вы хотите сгруппировать элементы по кол-ву символов.

Подойдет вот такая сверточка:

```js
let arr = [171, 22, 37, 2, 123, 54, 8, 7];
console.log(JSON.stringify(group(arr)));

function group(arr) {
  // сворачиваем в объект, от которого возвращаем только массив из значений
  return Object.values(arr.reduce((a, e) => {
    // на каждой итерации свертки определяем кол-во символов элемента 
    let l = String(e).length;
    // если в аккумуляторе еще нет ключа с найденной длиной, добавляем 
    // пустой массив, если есть выбираем его, добавляем в этот массив элемент
    return (a[l] || (a[l] = [])).push(e), a;
  }, {})).map(arr => arr.sort()); 
}
```

---

Если не хотите не конструировать строку для выяснения длины, можно написать:

`let l = 1 + Math.floor(Math.log10(e))`

---

UPD: "развернутая" версия:

```js
let arr = [171, 22, 37, 2, 123, 54, 8, 7];
console.log(JSON.stringify(group(arr)));

function group(arr) {

  let groups = arr.reduce((acc, element) => {
  
    let length = String(element).length;
    
    if (acc[length] === undefined)
      acc[length] = [];
      
    acc[length].push(element)
    
    return acc;
  }, {})
  
  return Object.values(groups).map(arr => arr.sort()); 
}
```

Comment: почему если написать `console.log(a[l])` до второго `return` выводит два раза подряд `undefined` а потом `[22, 37, 54]` потом опять `undefined` ?

Comment: еще можно пожалуйста поконкретнее объяснить вот эту часть `return (a[l] || (a[l] = [])).push(e), a;
    }, {}` буду очень благодарен .А то так смотрю и без понятия =(

Comment: я сейчас дополню ответ вторым примером где код делает то же самое, но надеюсь он будет Вам понятнее

Comment: Хорошо.Спасибо жду.

Comment: @Demon__ANT я давно дополнил ответ, однако забыл Вам написать об этом

Comment: спасибо теперь все ясно

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать написать такую функцию `getGrouppedArr`:

```
const testArr = [171, 22, 37, 2, 123, 54, 8, 7];

const getGrouppedArr = arr => {
  const arrWithLength = arr.map(item => ({
    value: item,
    length: item.toString().length
  }));

  const outputArr = [];

  arrWithLength.forEach(({ value, length }) => {
    const arrKey = length - 1;
    outputArr[arrKey] = outputArr[arrKey]
      ? [...outputArr[arrKey], value]
      : [value];
  });

  return outputArr;
};

console.log(getGrouppedArr(testArr)); // [ [2, 7, 8], [22, 37, 54], [123, 171] ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Вариант для "недырявых" массивов (без значений `undefined`):

```js
let arr = [171, 22, 37, 2, 123, 54, 8, 7]; 

console.log(JSON.stringify( foo(arr, 3) ));     // по три элемента
console.log(JSON.stringify( foo(arr, 9) ));     // с размером группы > размера массива
console.log(JSON.stringify( foo(arr, 1) ));     // с мин. размером группы
console.log(JSON.stringify( foo(arr, null) ));  // при корявых аргументах бросает исключение

function foo(arr, n) {
  if (!(arr instanceof Array) || !(n = +n) || !isFinite(n) || (n < 0))
    throw new TypeError('первый аргумент должен быть массивом, второй - числом >0'); 
  const sorted = arr.slice(0).sort((a, b) => a - b), 
        result = []; 
  do {
    let slice = sorted.splice(0, n); 
    if (typeof slice[0] === 'undefined') break; 
    result.push(slice); 
  } while (true); 
  return result; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Если есть возможность использовать lodash

```
Object.values(_.groupBy(arr.sort(), x => x.toString().length))
```